# What are views in Scala?

Tags: scala, view

I was reading http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/views.html, but I don't understand what the purpose of them is?

Please provide an example other than the one that is stated on the site.

Answer (score 0):

What they are is [deprecated](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629) as of [Scala 2.11](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.11.0) (under deprecations)

According to this [other tutorial](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html#view-bounds) a view bound is an implicit parameter that contains an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is defining a certain kind of implicit as a "view", but this terminology hasn't really caught on in the community (in part because "view" already means other things); most people (IME) would call the thing described in that link an "implicit conversion".

The best use case is the "pimp my library pattern", the equivalent of e.g. "extension methods" in other languages, i.e. for adding a new method onto a third-party type that you can't change yourself. Often you do this because third-party types "really" conform to some common superinterface, but the writer of the library didn't make their classes `extend' the appropriate type. Or you just do it to save yourself some typing. E.g. I recently did something like the following (type/method names are incorrect but should give you an idea) because the AWS API has a callback interface, but not a scala future interface

```
class PimpedAwsTransfer(inner: AwsTransfer) {
  def responseFuture = Future.fromCallback {
    cb => 
      inner.onSuccess(new AwsCallback({
        def callback(response: TransferResponse) = cb(transferResponse)
      }))
  }
}
implicit def pimpAwsTransfer(transfer: AwsTransfer) = new PimpedAwsTransfer(transfer)
```

Now `someTransfer.responseFuture` is a valid method call to make on an `AwsTransfer`, and will call the method I defined in `PimpedAwsTransfer`. So I can write code like:

```
for {
  response1 <- transfer1.responseFuture
  response2 <- transfer2.responseFuture
} yield {...}
```

(note that in modern scala you would use an `implicit class` rather than `class`+`implicit def`, but that's just sugar for the same thing)

I could have just had a static `convertAwsTransferToFuture()` function somewhere, but by putting the method on the `AwsTransfer` object I make the API more like one that I want to use. It's mostly about adapting to third-party types.

Some people also use these implicit conversions as conversions, i.e. to make a third-party type conform to their own interface. IMO this is a less good use as it can lead to very confusing code; such usages can usually be replaced by the typeclass pattern, using an implicit method parameter rather than an implicit conversion.

@Gangstead is correct that *view bounds* are deprecated in 2.11, but they're only a small piece of what your link was talking about.